# I am trying to run multiple query statements created when using the python connector with the same query id

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a Python function which creates multiple query statements.

Once it creates the SQL statement, it executes it (one at a time).

Is there anyway to way to bulk run all the statements at once (assuming I was able to create all the SQL statements and wanted to execute them once all the statements were generated)?   I know there is an execute_stream in the Python Connector, but I think this requires a file to be created first. It also appears to me that it runs a single query statement at a time."

Since this question is missing an example of the file, here is a file content that I have provided as extra that we can work from.

//connection test file for python multiple queries

```
import snowflake.connector

conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
   user = 'xxx',
   password = '',
   account = 'xxx',
   warehouse= 'xxx',
   database= 'TEST_xxx'
   session_parameters = {
      'QUERY_TAG: 'Rachel_test',
   }
}
```

while(conn== true){
   print(conn.sfqid)import snowflake.connector

```
try:
   conn.cursor().execute("CREATE WAREHOUSE IF NOT EXISTS tiny_warehouse_mg")
   conn.cursor().execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS testdb_mg")
   conn.cursor().execute("USE DATABASE testdb_mg")

   conn.cursor().execute(
        "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "
        "test_table(col1 integer, col2 string)")

   conn.cursor().execute(
        "INSERT INTO test_table(col1, col2) VALUES " +
        "    (123, 'test string1'), " + 
        "    (456, 'test string2')")
   break

except Exception as e:
   conn.rollback()
   raise e

}  
conn.close()
```

The reference to this question refers to a method that can be done with the file call, the example in documentation is as follows:

```
from codecs import open
   with open(sqlfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       for cur in con.execute_stream(f):
       for ret in cur:
           print(ret)
```

[Reference to guide I used](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#connecting-using-the-default-authenticator)

Now when I ran these, they were not perfect, but in practice I was able to execute multiple sql statements in one connection, but not many at once. Each statement had their own query id. Is it possible to have a .sql file associated with one query id?

Answer (score 0):

I believe though you generated the .sql while executing in snowflake each statement will have unique query id.

If you want to run one sql independent to other you may try with multiprocessing/multi threading concept in python.

Comment: Hi @sriga, do you mind sharing an example or a reference where I can learn more about this? Thank you kindly.

Comment: @Rachel McGigan I don't have script ready now.. Let me develope tonight I will post tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a .sql file associated with one query id?

You can achieve that effect with the [QUERY_TAG](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#query-tag) session parameter. Set the QUERY_TAG to the name of your .SQL file before executing it's queries.  Access the .SQL file QUERY_IDs later using the QUERY_TAG field in [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html)().

Answer (score 0):

The Python and Node.Js libraries do not allow multiple statement executions.
I'm not sure about Python but for Node.JS there is this library that extends the original one and add a method call "ExecutionAll" to it:
[snowflake-multisql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snowflake-multisql)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to wrap multiple statements with the BEGIN and END.

BEGIN

<statement_1>;

<statement_2>;

END;

With these operators, I was able to execute multiple statement in nodejs

Answer (score 0):

If you use the anonymous code block in snowflake, you can execute multiple statements together.

```
conn.cursor().execute(f"""
execute immediate $$     
begin

create table try_1 like test_table;
create table try_2 like test_table;

end;
$$
""")
```

Both statements are executed as a single block of code.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work if you are using the 'set' statement to set variables and use those variables later in a query

Comment: @mike01010 I tried and I don't know how to set variables inside the code block (yet :P), but the good thing is that you can declare and use variables as you like inside the anonymous code block, much more flexibly than regular queries. Does that not solve the problem?